# Intersection of Segre variety with linear spaces

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, tensor-rank

Consider the intersection of the Segre variety associated to product of $n$ copies of $\mathbb P^2$, with $k$ linearly independent hyperplanes. Is it possible to drop one of the hyperplanes and obtain the same zero-set?

Alternatively, let $S$ be the set of rank $1$ tensors in $\mathbb R^3 \otimes\ldots \otimes \mathbb R^3$ (n times) which are annihilated by  $T_1,\ldots, T_k \in ({\mathbb R^3})^*\otimes \ldots\otimes ({\mathbb R^3})^* $ (n times). Is it true that if $T_1, \ldots, T_k$ are linearly independent then no subset of them can define $S$?

Thanks

Comment: If $k$ is large enough that the intersection is empty, then yes.  Are there some constraints here?

Comment: Yes, I know that the intersection has positive dimension.

Comment: It seems that this is possible: http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/notemat/article/viewFile/1045/869